# Поиск в результатах querySelectorAll

Tags: javascript

Я делаю userscript, который должен сначала извлечь все ссылки по селектору, а потом искать только среди содержимого этих ссылок, возможно изменяя атрибуты в найденных элементах. Можно ли при каждом поиске не выполнять извлечение всех ссылок?

Пример:

```
var links=document.querySelectorAll('a.some_class');

// здесь некоторые действия с атрибутами href

//этот код мог бы быть решением, но не работает, как мне необходимо 
//селектор зависит от действий с переменной links,
//то есть сразу использовать a.some_class[href$="some_href"] b нельзя

links.querySelectorAll('a[href$="some_href"] b')[0].style.display='none'; 
//NodeList не имеет этого метода

//по-другому 
//можно попробовать создать document fragment, у которого есть такой метод
var fragment=document.createDocumentFragment();
for(var i=0; i<links.length; i++){
   fragment.appendChild(links[i]); 
   //ссылка удаляется со страницы, поэтому этот вариант тоже не подходит
}
```

Можно, конечно, просто использовать цикл по links, но это будет довольно медленно.

Comment: вам на so правильно ответили (только мне кажется filter был бы удобнее, чем each) ну и [вот ещё это бывает](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.matches)

Comment: @eicto решение на SO — это цикл. Метод, конечно, полезный, но в данном случае, по-моему, его можно использовать только для проверки сразу нескольких атрибутов. Или я не прав?

Comment: ну операции с dom тоже дорогие, клонирование там... еще непонятно что хуже, все таки цикл у вас по верхним представителям, а клон - всех деревьев

Comment: @eicto Как я пояснил в комментарии, ответ с клонированием в любом случае не годится. По-видимому, цикл на самом деле единственное решение.